# Get Parameter from URL using PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a url:

domain.com/?city=newyork&postback=test

I am currently successfully passing the postback parameter using the PHP below. However, I can not figure out how to also pass the city parameter.

```
<?php session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['postback'])) {
    if($_GET['postback'] == "") {
        header ("Location: qualify-step2.php?postback=".$_SESSION['postback']);
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Can someone please help me edit the code successfully? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the superglobal $_GET for accessing those variables.  This is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this

```
<?php session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['postback'])) {
    if($_GET['postback'] == "") {
        header ("Location: qualify-step2.php?postback=".$_SESSION['postback']."&city=".$_SESSION['city']);
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: Did you just add `&city=".$_SESSION['city']` to the end of URL ? Why did you do that? your condition is  `if($_GET['postback'] == "")`, it is mean, this parameter is null.

Comment: You're a good man with outstanding character. Good karma is headed your way my friend

Comment: I'm completely lost with this stuff, tried hacking with the code but I was missing the "." at the end of .$_SESSION['postback']

Answer (score 2):

You should use the $_GET superglobal to get params from url... In your case $_GET['city'] holds the value newyork and $_GET['postback']  holds the value test.

Comment: `postback` param is on session.

Comment: The url has the postdata param that holds value "test"

Answer (score 0):

For geting parameter from URL, you should use `$_GET['param'];`.

**Note:** In here, You should use *Get method* for sending data.